# Write as many 1 in vector as there are rows in matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
mat = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2)
```

and I wish to create the vector

```
vec = c(1,1)
```

which contains as many 1 that there are lines in the matrix.

How to do it fast?

Comment: You mean `rep(1, nrow(mat))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by lines you mean rows you can use `rep`

```
rep(1, nrow(mat))
#[1] 1 1
```

Comment: One last small question: I need to create a 1x6 vector by using ```rep(1, nrow(mat))``` and ```c(0,0,0,0)```. How to do it?

Comment: You mean `c(rep(1, nrow(mat)), c(0,0,0,0))` or `matrix(c(rep(1, nrow(mat)), c(0,0,0,0)))` ?

Answer (score 1):

On the suspicion that you might be trying to creating the column vector of `1`s for the design matrix of a linear regression (i.e. the "dummy" data corresponding to the intercept term), you might also benefit from knowing this alternative:

```
model.matrix( ~ 1, data.frame(mat))
```

(LHS of the formula is irrelevant so it's left empty; `1` represents the constant term)